# Where can I find the sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json file and how is it leveraged?

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-gui

I'm new to OpenUI5 and I'm trying to understand how the OpenUI5 cache buster works by reading through the [documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/ff7aceda0bd24039beb9bca8e882825d). I don't understand where I can find the generated `sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json`. Am I supposed to be able to find it in my server (after build)? Or can I access it and read its content in some way? Am I supposed to see it in the list of files my browser receives in the network tab? Can I read it at all?

Comment: I think you can find it with the BSP somewhere if you deploy it to a gateway system

Comment: I'd suggest creating an issue at https://github.com/SAP-docs/sapui5/issues for improved documentation

Answer (score 0):

'sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json' file is generated on the server and usually located in the server root directory.

it's contains information about the version of the OpenUI5 library in use and the corresponding file names,

file content is not accessible to the client, it is read by the server when serving the library files. You can inspect it using browser development tools

Comment: by server you mean a SAP Cloud Platform, right? Because I have a openui5 frontend app that is sitting behind an nginx server, and I was pulling at my hair trying to understand why I wasn't getting that .json file.